# npm install failed at node-sass command failed

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

As title.  I've maintained a project that web page is developed using Angular.js and some utilities, but something wrong when I use the "npm install" command, and the error log was shown below....

```
2094 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Gary.Lu\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
2095 verbose node v16.13.1
2096 verbose npm  v8.3.0
2097 error code 1
2098 error path C:\Users\Gary.Lu\Documents\ITTS Projects\AXMES\MAIN\ITTS-MES\WEB\node_modules\node-sass
2099 error command failed
2100 error command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
2101 error Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Gary.Lu\Documents\MyWeb\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
2102 error gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
2102 error gyp verb cli [
2102 error gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
2102 error gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\Gary.Lu\\Documents\\MyWeb\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
2102 error gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
2102 error gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
2102 error gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
2102 error gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
2102 error gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
2102 error gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
2102 error gyp verb cli ]
2102 error gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
2102 error gyp info using node@16.13.1 | win32 | x64
2102 error gyp verb command rebuild []
2102 error gyp verb command clean []
2102 error gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
2102 error gyp verb command configure []
2102 error gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
2102 error gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
2102 error gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\Gary.Lu\Documents\MyWeb\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
2102 error gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\Gary.Lu\Documents\MyWeb\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
2102 error gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\Gary.Lu\Documents\MyWeb\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
2102 error gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Gary.Lu\Documents\MyWeb\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
2102 error gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Gary.Lu\Documents\MyWeb\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
2102 error gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Gary.Lu\Documents\MyWeb\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
2102 error gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
2102 error gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
2102 error gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\Gary.Lu\Documents\MyWeb\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
2102 error gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\Gary.Lu\Documents\MyWeb\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
2102 error gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\Gary.Lu\Documents\MyWeb\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
2102 error gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Gary.Lu\Documents\MyWeb\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
2102 error gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Gary.Lu\Documents\MyWeb\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
2102 error gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Gary.Lu\Documents\MyWeb\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
2102 error gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
2102 error gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
2102 error gyp verb `which` failed }
2102 error gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
2102 error gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Python310\python.EXE
2102 error gyp ERR! configure error 
2102 error gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Python310\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
2102 error gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
2102 error gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
2102 error gyp ERR! stack                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2102 error gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
2102 error gyp ERR! stack 
2102 error gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:397:12)
2102 error gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
2102 error gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
2102 error gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
2102 error gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19044
2102 error gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Gary.Lu\\Documents\\MyWeb\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
2102 error gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Gary.Lu\Documents\MyWeb\node_modules\node-sass
2102 error gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.1
2102 error gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
2102 error gyp ERR! not ok 
2102 error Build failed with error code: 1
2103 verbose exit 1
2104 timing npm Completed in 53164ms
2105 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1640746055969
2106 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:build 1640746094013
2107 verbose unfinished npm timer build 1640746094014
2108 verbose unfinished npm timer build:deps 1640746094014
2109 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:postinstall 1640746099176
2110 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:postinstall:node_modules/node-sass 1640746099176
2111 verbose code 1
2112 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
2112 error     C:\Users\Gary.Lu\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-12-29T02_47_34_408Z-debug-0.log
```

But I didn't met the same erroe when I build another project that using Angular 12.  Is it matters or do I missed something that I can't build without it?  Could someone guide me to solve it?

Comment: Your code is set up for Python 2, but you only have Python 3

Comment: I've installed Python 2.7.17 but found no effects. May I have more ways to solve it?

Comment: try downgrade Node version to 14.X

Comment: Put `python2` in your PATH

Comment: @sojin Your idea works for me! Thank you!

Comment: I had that problem but just the last answer worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/77500925/23073201

Answer (score 23):

I had this problem too,
what I did :

1- npm uninstall node-sass

2- npm i -D sass

3- npm i

Comment: I'm struggling googling what `-D` options does. What is it?

Comment: @andy4thehuynh its to install dependency as dev dependency.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens because your environment has changed since running npm install. Run npm rebuild node-sass to download the binding for your current environment."

So I ran  `npm rebuild node-sass` and that worked! Then npm install and everything went ok.

Answer (score 0):

node-sass require limited Node Version, you need check the node's version is which node-sass compatible.

Answer (score 0):

First of all figure out the Python version and Node version used in your sass.
The node version can be found by searching in packages, it will look like this

```
 "engines": {
  "node": ">=8.0.0"
}
```

For python version in binding File

```
'python': ['<3.10.0>'],
```

Then install both the required versions for Node as well as Python

If you have nvm installed you can use

```
nvm install @version_name
```

For python you have to download the required version from the python website
and then add its value to system variables

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Uninstall `node-saas` by `npm uninstall node-sass --force`
2. Install "sass" by `npm install sass --force`
3. If get this error `Error: ../node_modules/@types/ws/index.d.ts` then install: `npm install -f @types/ws@8.5.4`

Also you can see here:
https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/3928#issuecomment-1816104992